# Django redirect() - argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Tags: django, redirect

```
from django.conf.urls import url    
import views


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^redirect/', views.redirct)

]



from django.shortcuts import redirect


def redirct(request):

    return redirect("http://google.com/")
```

Request Method: GET

Request URL: http://localhost/redirect/

Django Version: 1.11.1

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Comment: please add your imports to your question, where are you getting your redirect function? is it `django.shortcuts.redirect`?

Comment: Yes of course!
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok, I don't see why you would get that error. Please show the full traceback. As an aside, naming your view `redirct` is a bad idea -- it looks like a typo, especially when you are using `redirect` inside it. It's a good idea to terminate your regex as well, i.e. `r'^redirect/$'`.

Comment: I'll come up with a new name. I wanted to see how it works, but it does not work. $ Did not help. I tried other names

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: https://pastebin.com/K5Dtwkdv

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else in your url patterns. The code you have shown shouldn't cause that error.

Comment: I tried to transfer url in `Bubble.urls`... Does not work

Comment: urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^redirect/', views.redirct),

] once get a try with this

Comment: Does not work. Create a new project and try. UPD.In the clean project works

Comment: `aggregator = settings.PAYMENT['aggregator'] + '.urls' url(r'^payment/', include(aggregator))` This causes an error

Comment: HttpResponseRedirect works, redirect does not work.... Ok...